# json_encode, ассоциативные массивы

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, меня интересует следующая задача. Есть массив, который нужно преобразовать в JSON

```
json_encode([
            'status' => 'error',
            'errors' => [
                'code' => 400,
                'message' => 'This login already exists'
            ]
        ], true)
```

И после преобразования я получаю

```
{
"status": "error",
"errors": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "This login already exists"
 }
}
```

Можно ли как-то указать чтобы "errors" оставался массивом, а не преобразовывался в объект. Чтобы в итогк был вот такой результат

```
{
"status": "error",
"errors": [
  "code": 400,
  "message": "This login already exists"
 ]
}
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: а зачем? если отдаете в js, там ассоциативный массив - это объект. да и стандарт, думаю, не позволяет

Comment: так нужно по заданию,  тут не я решаю

Comment: Но валидацию желаемый вами результат не проходит. так что, потом его декодировать стандартными средствами нельзя будет. И true можете убрать, там другие аргументы

Comment: в js нельзя написать так `[
  "code": 400,
  "message": "This login already exists"
 ]` ...........будет невалид...зачем нужно невалидный json?

Comment: это да, вы правы, но нужен такой формат, это не для js делается

Comment: делайте руками, функция не валидный json не сделает

Comment: А если читать будет php, можно не обязательно в json - serialize, например, сохранит ваш массив как строку